# Unable to get the output of python executed from Java

Tags: java, python, html, spring, spring-boot

I am actually working on my graduation project. I have to work with spring boot technology. I have to run a python script from a java code which will use input of a html form. I have prepared my three files HTML, java and python

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <title>Add Info</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Insert an Info:</h1>
       
      <!--  
         In Thymeleaf the equivalent of
         JSP's ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/edit.html
         would be @{/edit.html}         
         -->
      <form th:action="@{/index}" method="get">
        <input type="text" th:name="Coord1"/> </br>
        <input type="text" th:name="Coord2"/> </br>
        <input type="text" th:name="Coord3"/> </br>
        <input type="text" th:name="Coord4"/> </br>
        <input type="text" th:name="datedeb"/> </br>
        <input type="text" th:name="datefin"/> </br>
        <input type="submit"/> 
        </form>
       
      <br/>
       
      <!-- Check if errorMessage is not null and not empty -->
       
      <div th:if="${errorMessage}" th:utext="${errorMessage}"
         style="color:red;font-style:italic;">
         ...
      </div>
       
   </body>
</html>
```

the java code:

```
package com.example.project.controller;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class MainController {
    float Coord1;
    float Coord2;
    public static String s;
 @RequestMapping(value="/index",method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public void addAObjectForm(@RequestParam("Coord1") float Coord1,@RequestParam("Coord2") 
 float Coord2,@RequestParam("Coord3") float Coord3, @RequestParam("Coord4")float Coord4,@RequestParam("datedeb") 
 String datedeb,@RequestParam("datefin") String datefin) throws IOException {
//System.out.println(Coord1);
try
{
     String pathPython = "test1.py";
     String [] cmd = new String[8];
     cmd[0] = "python";
     cmd[1] = pathPython;
     cmd[2] = "Coord1";
     cmd[3] = "Coord2";
     cmd[4] = "Coord3";
     cmd[5] = "Coord4";
     cmd[6] = "datedeb";
     cmd[7] = "datefin";         
     Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
     Process p = r.exec(cmd);
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
     while((s=in.readLine()) != null){
         System.out.println(s);
         System.out.println(Coord1);
         }
    // BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
}

catch(Exception e){
    
    
}

}
 }
```

and python code:

```
import sys
import os

def getDataFromJava(arg1=(sys.argv[0]),arg2=(sys.argv[1]),arg3=(sys.argv[2]),arg4=(sys.argv[3]),arg5=(sys.argv[4]),arg6=(sys.argv[5])):
cord1=arg1
cord2=arg2
cord3=arg3
cord4=arg4 
datedeb=arg5
datefin=arg6 
print(cord1)                                                                                                                                            
print(cord2)
#print(arg3_val)

return cord1,cord2,cord3,cord4,datedeb,datefin
```

when I am trying to be sure that my python script is returning a result, I get the String s in the java code equal to null

Any help please to get a result

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Firstly see [this](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/94-ignoring-exceptions-is-dangerous). Then post any errors

Answer (score 0):

```
# append to your current test1.py

import sys

getDataFromJava( \
        str(sys.argv[0]), str(sys.argv[1]), str(sys.argv[2]), \
        str(sys.argv[3]), str(sys.argv[4]), str(sys.argv[5]))
```

[Ref](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-command-line-arguments-argv-example/)
I am a beginner at python. I googled to find what I think is missing in your solution. I think the python function needs to be called, and shell parameters need to be retrieved and passed in to python function.

**Update 1**

Based on your edit, you have updated the function **definition** `def getDataFromJava(...):`. You have not added a function **call** `getDataFromJava(...)` below your function definition. I have provided a runnable script below.

```
import sys
import json

def getDataFromJava(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5,arg6):
    cord1=arg1
    cord2=arg2
    cord3=arg3
    cord4=arg4 
    datedeb=arg5
    datefin=arg6 

    return cord1,cord2,cord3,cord4,datedeb,datefin

print(json.dumps(getDataFromJava( \
    str(sys.argv[1]), str(sys.argv[2]), str(sys.argv[3]), \
    str(sys.argv[4]), str(sys.argv[5]), str(sys.argv[6]))))
```

---

```
$ python test1.py qw er ty ui op as
["qw", "er", "ty", "ui", "op", "as"]
```

I added json because I saw that you are returning a list of items back to java side. I thought that json will be a good data interchange format between your python side and your java side. Your java code now need to parse the returned json-formatted string. If you are returning a few items and want to skip json usage, you can return something like `abc#def#ghi#jkl`.

```
print('#'.join(getDataFromJava( \
    str(sys.argv[1]), str(sys.argv[2]), str(sys.argv[3]), \
    str(sys.argv[4]), str(sys.argv[5]), str(sys.argv[6]))))
```

Comment: Import sys is there from the beginning. I modified the getDataFromJava function as you mentioned but still i get null when I run BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
     while((s=in.readLine()) != null){
         System.out.println(s);
         System.out.println(Coord1);
         }

Comment: For people who don't do python, please change that script into something that will run in python and print to stdout (and prefrerably stderr too) *whilst reproducing your problem*

Comment: OK, I've now made your script testable. Your code runs for me, so the first place to look for your problem is the path to the script. Try making it full and absolute to begin with.